# Fit curve to histogram ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know that i can fit a density curve to my histogram in ggplot in the following way.

```
df = data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=..density..)) + geom_histogram() + geom_density()
```

[image: histogram]

However, I want my yaxis to be frequency(counts) instead of density, and retain a curve that fits the distribution. How do I do that?

Comment: The density will always be on a different scales than the counts since the density has to integrate to 1 by definition. So you are basically asking to have a plot with two different y scales which isn't possible in ggplot2 (at least not easily -- you can search this site to find examples). Why do you think you need both a histogram and an kernel density estimation? You usually go with one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your goals, something like this may work by just scaling the density curve using multiplication:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram() + geom_density(aes(y=..density..*10))
```

or

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram() + geom_density(aes(y=..count../10))
```

Choose other values (instead of 10) if you want to scale things differently.

## Edit:

Since you are defining your scaling factor in the global environment, you can define it within `aes`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram() + geom_density(aes(n=n, y=..density..*n)) 
# or
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, n=n)) + geom_histogram() + geom_density(aes(y=..density..*n))
```

or another, less nice way using `get`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  geom_density(aes(y=..density.. * get("n", pos = .GlobalEnv)))
```

Comment: i'm determining a scaling variable n outside the ggplot function. Then i call my ggplot function   `ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram() + geom_density(aes(y=..density..*n))`   I get an error Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'n' not found . Is there a way to pass in the scaling variable into geom_density?